# Prove that the measure of the image of a continuous, differentiable function is equal to $\int_Eg'(x)$.

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

**Problem:** Assume that a real-valued function $g$ is continuous and differentiable on an open interval containing $[0,1]$, an assume that there exist constants $c_1$ and $c_2$ such that $0 < c_1 \le g'(x) \le c_2$ for all $x \in [0,1]$. Prove that $\mu(g(E)) = \int_E g'(x)dx$ for every Lebesgue measurable set $E \subset [0,1]$.

**My attempt:** I've been able to prove the case where $E$ is an open interval, and $g$ is an increasing function. This case is obvious: $\mu(g((a,b))) = g(b)-g(a) = \int_a^bg'(t)dt$. When $E$ is an open set, $E$ can be written as a disjoint union of open intervals, so that case follows as well. However, I can't figure out how to generalize this to Lebesgue measurable sets and to non-increasing functions.

If $g$ is non-increasing, and $E$ is an open interval, we still have that $g(x) = g(a) + \int_a^x g'(t)dt$. But I can't seem to come with with an expression for even $\mu(g((a,b)))$ when $g$ is not continuous. Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You have $g'(x)\geq c_1>0$ on $[0,1]$, so that $g$ is increasing at least on $[0,1]$.

Comment: @PhoemueX... oh man... it's so simple... thank you.

Comment: To lift from open sets to general measurable sets: Do you know Dynkin's $\pi$-$\lambda$ theorem?

Comment: @PhoemueX I do, yes - I've gotten through the problem up to open sets, now. From here, is approximating any measurable set by an open set $F$ such that $m(F\setminus E)$ the way to finish off the problem?

Comment: I would just set $G := \{E \, \mid \, \mu(g(E)) = \int_E g'(x) \, dx\}$. Then show that this is a $\lambda$ system which contains the $\pi$ system of open sets.

Comment: Ah, got it. Thank you for your help! If you would like to make your comments an answer, I'll mark it correct, if not, I'll type up my own answer in a few days. Thanks!