# If $f$ measurable and $E \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ measurable, when will the set $f(E)$ be measurable?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

If $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ measurable and $E \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ measurable, examples show that $f(E) = \{ f(x) : x \in E \}$ may be unmeasurable.

My confusion is that under what assumptions about $f$ will the conclusion hold, i.e., $f(E)$ will be measurable. And is there an equivalence condition for this problem?

Comment: do you assume the axiom of choice? Vitali Theorem

Comment: Even if $f$ is a diffeomorphism, the set $f(E)$ can be unmeasurable...

Comment: look here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1437271/prove-that-the-measure-of-the-image-of-a-continuous-differentiable-function-is

Comment: @user659895 is there any counterexample for diffeomorphism?

Comment: I don't really know, but diffeoremorphism are Borel function, i.e. $f(B)$ is a borel set for $B$ a Borel set. So, if $E$ is measurable, but not Borel, there is no reason that $f(E)$ being measurable. If $f$ preserve null sets and $f$ is a homeomorphism, then $f(E)$ will be measurable for all measurable set $E$, simply because all measurable set differ from a Borel set by a null set.